# SharePoint 2010 Modal Dialog body color

Tags: 2010, development, branding

I have a link which opens my visual webpart inside Modal Dialog. I need to change the background color of Modal Dialog content area..dont want to make change in my custom css which is overiding corev4.css ..just want to make a change for a specific modal dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Apply this css..

.ms-dialog body #s4-workspace
{

```
     background-color:#F6F6F6;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write out the CSS as part of your web part if that's the only place that web part is shown. Unfortunately, you can't reliably target CSS for a child frame, so you can't include that background color as part of the link (and have it work across all browsers).

You could also add a user control to the masterpage that checks for a query string. If that query string is set, override the background color. That's likely a bit overkill for what you want (if it's a one off scenario), but that would allow you to assign the background color through the URL to the dialog source.